# How to set default runtime options for node?

Tags: node.js, io.js

I am using arrow functions in my code, thus I need to be using `--harmony_arrow_functions` option when running the code, e.g.

```
node --harmony_arrow_functions ./my-script.js
```

How do I make `--harmony_arrow_functions` a default option for every time I use `node`?

Answer (score 1):

Either add a wrapper script in your `PATH` that sets the command line options.

Or you could define a `start` script in your `package.json`.

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node --harmony_arrow_functions my-script.js"
    }
}
```

And run `npm start` to run your script.

Comment: ouch a wrapper script is ugly but AFAICT this is the only way to do it.